# ASP.NET Entity Framework Code First Migration process between environments

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I'm working in a team of four developers and we sometimes run into issues with EF Code First Migrations between different branches and releasing to staging from dev. We are using git.

What is the best process flow to follow between:

1. Devs working on different branches/features and eventually merging changes without loosing any migrations created in these branches/features.
2. Releasing to staging/live.

Comment: The best branching and release strategy is the one that works best for your organisation. There is no single best practice. I'd suggest you research some publicized strategies and see what fits best. Voting to close as primarily opinion based.

Comment: What issues you are facing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Read this [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn481501(v=vs.113).aspx) that addresses issues related to EF Code First Migrations in team environments.
2. There are a lot of branching strategies available out there, you could explore them and use the one that best suits your needs. Have a look at [git-flow](https://datasift.github.io/gitflow/IntroducingGitFlow.html), which is one of the branching models for Git.